# Select Items that Do Not StartsWith

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, boolean, observablecollection

I have a problem with my WinForm (Visual Studio 2017).

Before everything I thought giving you some details about it could benefit us all. I will only post the details I think are relevant to the question, so if you think I'm missing something feel free to tell me. Ask me also if I didn't explain some parts properly.
I used the `DataTableReader.GetSchemaTable` Method in order to do things, if that is relevant at all.

I wanted the elements of a list to be showed in a `Textbox` which would be then copied in a textfile, ecc ecc. Above the `Textbox` I made a `DataGrid` in which you can see the `NameField`s and there's a checkbox named "Able" that determines if those fields are gonna be shown (checked) in the `Textbox` below or not (unchecked).

First of all I made a class in which I set the properties I want in a collection, such as the Name and the condition "Able". I set it true by default (not shown here), so for all `NameField`s the tick in the `DataGridView` is currently checked. This means that they will show up in the `Textbox` below, ready to be "filetexted".

```
public class Info {
    public string NameField {get; set;}
    public bool Able {get; set;}
}
```

Then in another class I made an Observable Collection that would be filled with those `NameField`s created above (using the function `Fill` from `SqlDataAdapter`, which I won't show here).

```
public class Do {
    public ObservableCollection<Info> Projects = new ObservableCollection<Info>();
}
```

Finally I sorted the elements within that collection so that the elements that started with certain letters were the first to be shown (another user helped me on this one).

```
var change = Projects.OrderByDescending(c => 
    c.NameField.StartsWith("OS")).ToList();
Projects.Clear();
foreach (Info aInfo in change) {
    Projects.Add(aInfo);
}
```

Now what I need is that all elements in that same collection that DO NOT start with those letters would have their check on Able disabled. So that means that the `DataGrid` would have his tick under "Able" unchecked and those precise  `NameField`s won't appear in the `TextBox`.

I'm having real problems with this one and I can't seem to find a solution, so I'm asking you guys. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simple : c => !c.NameField.StartsWith("OS")  I added the not !

Comment: Do you ever keep a complete list of all instances of the `Info` class?

Comment: It is not really clear what you want here. If you only want to add the elements where the name field starts with 'OS' & ignore the ones that don't - why not just select the one you want. Alternatively, use a foreach loop through each element & set the Able flag based on what the name field starts with.

Comment: ObservableCollection was meant to be used by WPF.  BindingList was meant to be used by WinForms.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response, but I am also working on another project, which got me pretty busy. @jdweng thank you for the response, but I forgot to mention that I already knew the "reverse" of that function, the problem I had was that I didn't know how to put a control (maybe an IF) in order to select the ones which didn't startwith...

Comment: @PaulF you are right... I had in mind that in order to disable the fields (disable == false) that didn't meet the requirements I had to group them in a list or something and then make a control on that list

Comment: @ClayVerValen what do you mean with that?

Comment: "OS" is a string so you can replace with a variable.

Comment: @jdweng yes, I know, but unless I'm misinterpreting that doesn't really answer my question... Maybe you can add your answer with a code so I can understand it better?

Comment: @LarsTech noted.

Comment: Where is `Projects` populated? We only see it initialized as an empty collection. You should set `Able` where the collection is populated.

Comment: @GertArnold I thought showing the population of Projects wasn't necessary, but you are right, I needed to set `Able` like you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for how to sort your collection so that the elements that starts with
your sort/search criteria is listed on top and so that all the .Able fields in the elements
that meets the sort/search criteria is set true while the rest is set false.

The code listing includes the class for your Info objects, a class with a method to do the sorting and updating of your collection. And at the end a class with a method to test that it all works. 
I hope the code listing below is commented enough to make it self explainable.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace TestSpace
{
    public class Info //Your original class for the project info objects.
    {
        public string NameField { get; set; }
        public bool Able { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProjectSorter  //COMMENT: Renamed your "Do" class to "ProjectSorter" since it seems more understandable.
    {
        // COMMENT:
        // In this proposed solution the SortProjects method is changed so that it now takes two parameters.        
        // The parameters are the project collection to be sorted, and the sort/search criteria.The procject  
        // collection to be sorterd is sent by ref so that any changes to it is reflected back to the caller.
        // (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref for more
        // information on passing objects by ref.)

        public void SortProjects(ref ObservableCollection<Info> projectCollectionToSort, string sortCriteria)
        {
            // As allready solved this will sort the collection based on the sort criteria into a new list.
            var updatedProjectList =
            projectCollectionToSort.OrderByDescending(c => c.NameField.StartsWith(sortCriteria)).ToList();

            // Using the list's .ForeEach method we iterate through the new list and uses a lambda expression
            // to set .Able to true or false based on the sort/search criteria.
            updatedProjectList.ForEach(c => {
                if (c.NameField.StartsWith(sortCriteria)) { c.Able = true; } else { c.Able = false; }
            });

            // We then reset our collection to a new ObservableCollection<Info> and fills it with the new 
            // sorted and updated list.
            projectCollectionToSort = new ObservableCollection<Info>(updatedProjectList);

            // Work done.
        }
    }

    public static class TestTheCode
    {
        // Method to test the ProjectSorter.SortProjects() method.
        public static void RunSortCollectionTest()
        {
            ProjectSorter projectSorter = new ProjectSorter();

            // Just for the purpose of this example an example collection is populated
            // here with some data to work with.
            // As you describe for your list the default value for Able is set to true.
            ObservableCollection<Info> projects = new ObservableCollection<Info>()
            {
                new Info { NameField="PER", Able = true},
                new Info { NameField="ALEX", Able = true},
                new Info { NameField="OSCAR", Able = true},
                new Info { NameField="ANDY", Able = true}
            };

            // We sort the collection "projects" by sending it by ref to the projectSorter.SortProjects()
            // method, together with the sort/search criteria.
            projectSorter.SortProjects(ref projects, "OS");

            // To display that the collection "projects" are now sorted as intended, and that all the
            // .Able fields are satt correctly true or false, we iterate through the projects collection 
            // and print the values for NameField and Able to the Output window (debug).
            foreach (Info aInfo in projects)
            {
                Debug.Print(aInfo.NameField + "  -->  " + aInfo.Able);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To run the test just call `TestTheCode.RunSortCollectionTest()` from your code.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I also would like an explanation on your choice of coding, especially the reason for your putting `Able = false` along all of those fields. If I may ask, did you test this code?

Comment: @MadSkunk, thank you for your input. I have now spent a little more thought on it and rewritten my suggestion. And, of course, the code is tested. I always test my code, don't we all? ;) I hope the code listing is commented enough to make it self explainable. But if there's any questions or comments please share them.

Comment: @Simone, thank you for your input/questions, please see comment above.